# php showing error when getting the values from an array

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

In php I have my code something like this

```
  $discounts =  $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($product_id);
      $product_discounts[] = array();
      foreach($discounts as $discount) {
        $product_discounts[] = array(
          'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
          'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')))
        );
      }
```

Now when I made  it showed my array like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_discount_id] => 483 [product_id] => 43 [customer_group_id] => 8 [quantity] => 2 [priority] => 1 [price] => 345.0000 [date_start] => 0000-00-00 [date_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [1] => Array ( [product_discount_id] => 484 [product_id] => 43 [customer_group_id] => 8 [quantity] => 4 [priority] => 2 [price] => 784.0000 [date_start] => 0000-00-00 [date_end] => 0000-00-00 ) [2] => Array ( [product_discount_id] => 485 [product_id] => 43 [customer_group_id] => 8 [quantity] => 5 [priority] => 3 [price] => 786.0000 [date_start] => 0000-00-00 [date_end] => 0000-00-00 ) )
```

But when I made my code to get the values of discount quantity and discount price from the array

```
 <?php foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
    echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?>
    } ?>
```

I got the error like this `Undefined variable: discounts`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this

```
$product_discounts[] = array();
```

with

```
$product_discounts = array();
```

Comment: This isn't actually an error, and doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

`$discounts` has never been defined. It should be `$product_discounts`. That is why your are getting `undefined variable discounts`.

```
<?php
foreach ($product_discounts as $discount) {
    echo sprintf($text_discount, $discount['quantity'], $discount['price']); ?>
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$discounts =  $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($product_id);
  $product_discounts = array();
  foreach($discounts as $discount) {
    $product_discounts = array(
      'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
      'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')))
    );
  }
```